# Installation last version from SFML gives undefined reference to udev

Tags: c++, installation, redhat, sfml

I am trying to install the latest version of SFML from the git repositories on redhat 6.4, i have installed the depedency udev as :

```
 yum install libudev-devel.x86_64.
```

But when i try to compile SFML i got these errors :

```
../../lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value(udev_device*, char const*)'
../../lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref(udev_device*)'
../../lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(udev_device*, char const*, char const*)'
../../lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1: undefined reference to `udev_new()'
../../lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname(udev*, char const*, char const*)'
../../lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1: undefined reference to `udev_unref(udev*)'
```

Could somoene explain where my problem comes from and how could i solve it ?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: No my problem is a bit too specific, its not code related but library related, it may come from SFML configuration or sth...

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate why you guys can't understand this ? it seems you are not even TRYING to understand but just answering like robots because my thread 'looks like' something else...

Comment: The problem with those package is that they aren't official so there's no guarantee they work out of the box. Try the official package [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/). You can also build SFML yourself; it should easy if you follow **carefully** the official tutorial. Have a look [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php)

Comment: Ho no the official package works just fine already... I am using the one from repository because it provides better error handling...

Comment: Ho, sorry, I misread your question. I thought you did `yum install sfml`... stupid me. Now I see two possibilities: either you need to link your project against udev or your udev binaries don't have those symbols and you need to rebuild them correctly.